# How can I bridge HTTP and SMPP with Camel?

Tags: java, http, apache-camel, smpp

The following code tries to set up a Camel route to receive HTTP POSTs and send them as SMS messages via SMPP:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class SMSA {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                errorHandler(loggingErrorHandler());

                from("jetty:http://localhost:9993").
                    setHeader("CamelSmppDestAddr", header("deliveryAddress")).
                    to("smpp://smppclient1@localhost:2775?password=password&sourceAddr=1234")
                ;
            }
        };
        builder.addRoutesToCamelContext(context);
        context.start();
    }
}
```

This seems to work at first (SMS are sent), but the messages are all empty.

I use the following command to test:

```
curl -X POST -d "Hello World!" --header "Content-Type:text/plain" "http://localhost:9993?deliveryAddress=1818"
```

If I add a custom Processor and call

```
exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)
```

(as per example on http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html), then I can see the posted message.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out myself - the fix for me was to change the route to:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:9993").
    setHeader("CamelSmppDestAddr", header("deliveryAddress")).
    setHeader("CamelSmppAlphabet", constant(4)).
    to("smpp://smppclient1@localhost:2775?password=password&sourceAddr=1234")
;
```

Looking at some code somewhere between Camel 2.9.0 and 2.11.0 the behaviour seems to have changed to expect a byte[] by default unless an alphabet is explicitly defined. Since I posted a text/plain body it didn't work.